# Writing a list to a file and reading it back

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner and I have searched for my answer in this forum, and have tried to follow examples (many are more complex than I can understand at this point).  I want to write my list, Variables, to a file and read it back when necessary.

```
a = 'M'
b = 456.78
c = 100
Variables = [a, b, c]
f = open("test5.txt", "w")
with open("test5.txt", "r") as opened_file:
    for variable in Variables:
         "test5.txt".write(variable, '\n')
```

I get a "AttributeError" 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

1. What do I change?
2. How would i read it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means you can't write to a string, instead you want to write to the opened file. Change the string `test5.txt` to the file you've opened `f`:

```
for variable in Variables:
    f.write("%s\n" % variable)
f.close()
```

then read it back:

```
with open("test5.txt", "r") as opened_file:
    variables = opened_file.readlines()

print(variables) #will print the file contents
```

**Edit:** as discussed in the comments, the original request to re-assign the values to the appropriate variable names is not possible, the next best option would be to assign each value read from the file to their indices in the original list. Unfortunately the original datatypes are lost, keeping only the string value.

```
for i in range(len(variables)):
    Variables[i] = variables[i].strip()

print(Variables) # ['M', '456.78', '100']
```

Comment: Can you explain how my "...write(variable, '\n') differs from your ("%s\n" % variable)?  Is it just another way to code, or is mine wrong?

Comment: Sure, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) on writing to files says the argument to `file.write(str)` takes only 1 string argument, but `(variable, '\n')` is 2 arguments, the first an integer, and the second a string. `"%s\n" % variable` is one string using c-style formatting. So you could cast the variable into a string, `str(variable)`, then concatenate those into one string with the `+` operator. Then `f.write(str(variable)+'\n')` would work just the same.

Comment: I am sorry to pester.  When I read the file back, which I did and it prints out the values perfectly, but how do I re-assign the values to the appropriate variable names so that I can do calculations using the variable names like b or c?

Comment: No worries pester away..! =) That's a great question, I'm trying to figure that one out now.. :)

Comment: downshift-- i looked on this forum on how to do what I wanted, and they basically said "don't do that", instead just reference the list, as in Variables[2] if I wanted the value of c.  -not what I wanted, but might as well do it the way they say.  thanks

Comment: Yep, that's the best information I could find too. glad you figured it out.